# vuetify filter and sort v-data-table with a formatted date column

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a **v-data-table** with a column that is in milliseconds thet I formatted with moment like this:
`<td>{{ props.item.creationDate | moment("h:mm D.M.YYYY") }}`
I want to use the default sorting and filtering of vuetify but it turns out that if I'm formatting the date for display the filtering is not working because it is filtering the data itself which is not formatted, and if I'm formatting the data itself, the sort is not working because it is trying to sort the string formatted date.. is there a way to use the default sort and filter with my case or I have to use custom-filter/custom-sort?

Comment: You will need a custom filter - the built-in one only looks for the keys defined as column value(s) in the header definition.

Answer (score 0):

In vuetify 3 with Nuxt 3 this could be solved simply by defining the headers with separate value and key parameters. Sorting will apply sort based on the key:

```
const headers = ref ([
...
  {title: 'Creation Date', align: 'start', value: 'creationDate', key: 'rawCreationDate'}
...
])
```

Define rawCreationDate so that it carries the sortable value for date:

```
rawCreationDate: new Date(creationDate).getTime()
```